# React - useMemo without dependencies array vs empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

What is the difference between doing

```
const value = useMemo(() => {
     ...
});
```

and

```
const value = useMemo(() => {
     ...
}, []);
```

?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Using `useMemo()` without dependencies array will calculate the `value` on [every render](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo).

> If no array is provided, a new value will be computed on every render.

It'll be equivalent to

```
const value = ...
```

Using `useMemo()` with an empty dependencies array will calculate the `value` only once, on mount.

Demo:

```js
const App = () => {
    const value1 = React.useMemo(() => {
      console.log('calculating value1');
    });
    const value2 = React.useMemo(() => {
      console.log('calculating value2');
    }, []);
    const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);
    return (
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>{counter}</button>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: So, if there's a value specified in that array, and that value changes, there will be a re-render cycle?

Comment: `function useMemo<T>(factory: () => T, deps: DependencyList | undefined): T;` deps is mandatory, best thing is provide an `undefined` value

Comment: Is a useMemo with an empty dependency array conceptually different than a useEffect with an empty array? Because the useArray would only run on the first render?

Comment: @Aetos11 Yes, they're for different purposes. `useMemo` will run its callback immediately, and evaluates to a value. `useEffect` runs its callback only after the component has finished running, and does not evaluate to a value, and allows for a cleanup function to be returned.

Answer (score -7):

useMemo hook needs an array of dependencies, it's required.

Comment: just like @CertainPerformance said, and quoted from the React docs `If no array is provided, a new value will be computed on every render.`

Comment: If you open https://unpkg.com/react@16.14.0/umd/react.development.js (or later) you will see that it has the following signature, TypeScript complains if deps is omitted. Is the doc outdated?: `function useMemo(create, deps)`

Comment: I agree with @Rostyslav Nabok, In typescript, if you use `useMemo` you have to pass the second dependency array which is required.